# When should I make a Moose class immutable when I'm actually using ->meta?

Tags: perl, moose

Normally I would finalize a class at compilation via `__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable` at the end of the class. However, when should I be making a class immutable that composes roles into itself at runtime? Should I even be doing so to get better performance or is this imcompatible with `make_immutable`? `make_immutable` seems to speed up instantiation of the object, but does it do anything once the object is instantiated?

For example, something along the lines of:

```
BUILD {
  my $self = shift;
  use Module::Load;

  ### Use the arguments passed in to determine roles applicable to 
  ### this instance of the object. Load and apply roles.
  for my $role ($self->_determine_roles()) { 
    load $role;
    $role->meta->apply($self);
  }

  ### $self is now a Class::MOP::Class::__ANON__... anonymous class
  ### Should I then be saying I'm done mutating it with something like this?
  ### can make_immutable even be run on an object instance and not a package?
  $self->meta->make_immutable;
}
```

Even if the code above works for a single package, what happens when a object reblesses itself with the `'Foo'` role, resulting in a anonymous class, then a second object blesses itself with a `'Foo'` (becoming that same anon class) then `'Bar'` role? Is it going to work correctly when the second object blesses itself into the immutable first anonymous class, then tries applying the role to the now-immutable anonymous class to create a new anonymous class?

From reading the docs on [Moose::Meta::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aClass), it appears only a class can be immutable, not instances of objects. If so, should I just be ignoring `make_immutable` as I am mutating my classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be doing `make_immutable` as usual at the bottom of your class, and not worrying about it at all in your `BUILD`.

When you apply a role to an instance at runtime it doesn't modify the instance's class to apply the role (that would be messy and horrible and affect all other instances of that class); it creates a new anonymous class that inherits from your class and does the requested roles as well, and then reblesses the instance into that class. Since the original class isn't being modified there's no issue of whether it's open/mutable or not.

You actually *can* do `$self->meta->make_immutable` after the role application — it will immutabilize the newly-created anonymous class — and for completeness you probably should.  But it will only give a small benefit, since most of what `make_immutable` does is to make the constructor faster, and the new class's constructor doesn't run anyway.

If you want to see the details of how role application to instances works, you should peek at the source of [Moose::Meta::Role::Application::ToInstance](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose::Meta::Role::Application::ToInstance).

Comment: And even when I set the new anonymous class to immutable, extending it is still creating another anonymous class that encapsulates both the first immutable anon class and the new immutable role, so applying roles to the immutable anonymous class will still work properly. Got it!